OpenLayer Drag Rotate the map ONLY
how do we rotate the openlayer map by dragging and holding either shift or control key?
So far what i have tried is to follow the tutorial and samples, but I only found DragRotateZoom and there is no DragRotate in the API documentation
const map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        zoom: 2,
      }),
      
      interactions: ol.interaction.defaults.defaults().extend([
         new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom()
      ])
    });

I dont want the zoom as I am making a survey application and it is annoying when zoom occurs when rotating, how to solve this?

You can use the options to remove unwanted interactions from the defaults.  You can also combine conditions, for example
   const map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        zoom: 2,
      }),
      
      interactions: ol.interaction.defaults.defaults({shiftDragZoom: false, altShiftDragRotate: false}).extend([
         new ol.interaction.DragRotate({condition: function(e) {
           return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(e) || ol.events.condition.altShiftKeyOnly(e)
         })
      ])
    });


found the solution
  // Create the DragRotate interaction
  var dragRotate = new ol.interaction.DragRotate({
    condition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly  // Rotate only when Shift key is pressed
  });

  // Add the DragRotate interaction to the map
  map.addInteraction(dragRotate);

However i need to disable the drag zoom as I dont need that feature
  // Remove any DragZoom interaction if it was added previously
  map.getInteractions().forEach(function(interaction) {
    if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DragZoom) {
      map.removeInteraction(interaction);
    }
  });

